# Best Way To Update Another Redux Store From Redux-Saga Function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a React/Redux app and I chose to organize the Redux state into 2 main sections, ads and tasks and am using combineReducers.

Ads are created first. A single ad or a collection of ads can be grouped and assigned to a new task.

In my ads store I have reducers and saga functions that make the api calls related to ads and update the Redux state for ads.

In my task store I have reducers and saga functions that make api calls related to tasks and update the Redux state for tasks.

When a task is created from a collection of ads I need to update the Ads Redux state. Originally I was just dispatching my ads action creator that makes an api call and retrieves an updated list of all ads. Unfortunately that api call is a very complicated query and as a result fairly time consuming.

When I make the api call to create the task I get some data back that I could use to update the ads Redux state with avoiding having to make that slow api call.

Because multiple ads can go into creating a task my ad id's are stored in an array.

I'm trying to figure out how I can loop through that array and dispatch a reducer in the ads Redux store to update state with this data.

One issue I ran into is an error stating that yield can not be called from inside the forEach loop I was using to iterate over the array of ad id's.

The other issue is just finding the best way to update state from one Redux store in another.

I suppose I could just combine everything into a single Redux store but that file would be endlessly long.

Not sure which direction to go here.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue making this difficult was figuring out how to use yield put inside a loop.

This ended up working:

```
yield myArray.map((item: string) => 
    put(OtherReduxStoreActions.myActionCreatorFunction(item))
);
```